# Finding a substring in Python

Tags: python, regex

Is there a fast and pythonic way to search for a string within another string, and then assign it to a variable?

So far, I've only been able to get the index where the inner string starts:

```
text = "helothere"
a = text.find('helo')
print a # this prints '0'
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  If you already have the string you're searching for why would you then save that string to a variable...

Comment: I know I have "helo" inside the `text` variable. What I want is to extract that string ("helo") and assign it to a new variable

Comment: How about `b = "helo"`?

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps something like this:

```
a = 'helo' if 'helo' in text else ''
```

Comment: This is definitely the most "pythonic" way.

Comment: You should  use `""` not  None as it may cause problems if you later try comparing None to a string in python 3

Answer (score 2):

Why not just

```
if text.find(the_string) != -1:
    a = the_string
```

Since you know the string you're seeking / assigning from the start.

Comment: don't use `str` as a variable name

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
text = "helothere"
a = "helo"
if a in text:
    print a
else:
    a=''
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there... since you've found the index of where the substring starts, you can just splice the string between the start index you found using `find` and then length of the substring you're looking for...

```
text = "helothere"
a = text.find('helo')

# ...

foundStringLength = len('helo')
myResult = text[a:foundStringLength]

print(myResult)
```

There are a bunch of better ways to do this, but I figured I'd post an alternative to what's been said already.

More general version:

```
myTextToSearch = "" # define the string to search, through a function arg or something
mySubstringToSearchFor = "" # same deal here
searchStringLength = len(mySubstringToSearchFor)

startIndex = myTextToSearch.find(mySubstringToSearchFor)

if startIndex == -1:
    pass # didn't find the substring... return False/None/etc.
else:
    myResult = myTextToSearch[startIndex:searchStringLength]

    # now do stuff with the result!
    print(myResult)
    return myResult
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're actually trying to get at, but will this solve your problem?

```
text = "helothere"
term = "helo"

a = term if term in text else 'Term not in text'
```

You can assign else to whatever you want.

Comment: This is the same as [@Shashank's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27511040/4009370).

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function to do it:

```
def find_text(text, s):
    return text if text in s else None

text = "helothere"
print find_text("helo", text)  # --> helo
print find_text("not", text)   # --> None
```